# How do I ensure that a piece of hard code only gets called, when on my appointed Blog page?

Tags: php, blog

I have placed the following Blog Loop into my 'index.php' file:

```
<?php
    if ( have_posts() ):
        while( have_posts() ): the_post(); 
?>
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3> 
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
    <small>This entry was posted on: <?php the_date('l, jS F Y'); ?> at <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?> and is filed under <?php the_category(); ?></small>

    <?php 
            endwhile;
        endif;
    ?>
```

On my Home page, the above code does not call any Blog Posts as I have appointed a 'Blog' page for my Blogs.  That said, the above `<small>This entry was posted on: <?php the_date('l, jS F Y'); ?> at <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?> and is filed under <?php the_category(); ?></small>` is appearing on my Home page as well as other pages.  I realise that this is because I have hard coded it into my index.php but how do I remove this.  If I simply remove it from my code, it does not appear on my appointed Blog page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve the issue.  The code I used, should anyone find themselves in a similar situation, is as follows:

```
<?php if( is_home() ): ?>   
<h1>Blog Page</h1>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php 
if ( have_posts() ): 
while( have_posts() ): the_post();
?>  

    <?php if( is_home() ): ?>   
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3> 
    <?php the_content();?>
    <small>This entry was posted on: <?php the_date('l, jS F Y'); ?> at <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?> and is filed under <?php the_category(); ?></small>;

    <?php else: ?>
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3> 

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

what about surrounding it in the if is_home() statement so it only shows on your blog page?

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ):
    while( have_posts() ): the_post(); 
?>
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3> 
<p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
if ( is_home() ) :?>
    <small>This entry was posted on: <?php the_date('l, jS F Y'); ?> at <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?> and is filed under <?php the_category(); ?></small>
<?php 
endif;
        endwhile;
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input rudtek.  Whilst your coding brought up a few errors, it pointed me in the right direction.  I have placed my coding in the answers, should you want to refer to it in case you had errors yourself.

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help.  Would love the credit for answer if you don't mind.